# On the results of François Viète

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

After learning this in middle school, I haven't stopped thinking about it to this day. I have attempted to prove it myself, but to no avail. If we have $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$; for simplicity, divide both sides by $a$ and let us have $x^2 + px + q = 0$ (where $p = $$b\over a$ and $q = $$c\over a$). Viète showed the relation between the coefficients and the roots of this equation to be
$$x_1 + x_2 = -p \text{ and }x_1x_2 = q.$$

From you, reader, I request the proof of these two statements. Desirably, I also request the proof for Viète's results for an equation of the $n$th degree.

Show that if $x^n + a_1x^{n - 1} + a_2x^{n - 2} + ... + a_n = 0$ and the roots of this equation be $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, then the following equations hold:
$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = -a_1$ (the sum of the product of the roots taken one at a time)

$x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + ... x_{n-1}x_n = a_2$ (the sum of the product of the roots taken two at a time

...

$x_1 x_2 x_3 ... x_n = a_n$, if $n$ is even; $x_1 x_2 x_3 ... x_n = -a_n$, if $n$ is odd (the sum of the product of the roots taken $n$ at a time)

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it yourself! Here are the steps:

1. Suppose the roots of $p(x) = 0$ are $x_1, \dots, x_n$ (listed with multiplicity).
2. Show that $p(x) = (x-x_1) \cdots (x-x_n)$.
3. Expand this product to find expressions for the coefficients in terms of the roots.

Answer (score 0):

If you factorise your monic polynomial as: $$p(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$$Where possibly some $a_i$ have been repeated, then you just have to expand this term by term. How many ways can you make a power of $x^{n-1}$? Well, you have to multiply by one constant term and all other multiplications have to be by an “$x$”. That gives $-a_1x^{n-1}$, or $-a_2x^{n-1}$, etc. and the total coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is seen to be $-(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)$. Proceed similarly with the others.

If you want to make this “more formal” you could induct.